# Trouble configuring Angular Routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have 3 levels of routing: `app.module` > `admin.module` > `manage-users.module`.

For some reason the URL path that matches `''` redirects to the `''` path in `manage-users.module` instead of `HomeComponent`.

I have the following routes in my app.routing:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    {
        path: 'details',
        loadChildren: './details/details.module#DetailsModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            ROUTES,
            { enableTracing: true, useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: NoPreloading } // <-- debugging purposes only
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My admin routing:

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivateChild: [ AdminGuard ],
                children: [
                    {   path: 'users',
                        loadChildren: './manage-users/manage-users.module#ManageUsersModule'
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: AdminDashboardComponent
                    }
                ]
            },

        ],
        canActivate: [ AdminGuard ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {
}
```

My manage users routing:

```
const manageUsersRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ManageUsersComponent,
    }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(manageUsersRoutes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class ManageUsersRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: What does your imports array look like for these modules?

Comment: they declare & export their own components within their features.

Comment: I think he want's to know how you're configuring the router module inside your feature modules imports. Because it looks like you're overriding your routes. Are you sure you are using `RouterModule.forChild` inside your feature module imports.

Comment: @DeborahK moving the first object in the routes array to the last really fixed the problem,is there anything else?

Comment: Double check your "feature modules" that there is no "RouterModule.forRoot" inside the imports array.

Comment: none of my features modules have a forRoot method, only my `app-routing.module

Answer (score 1):

I was asking more what the imports array looks like. Something like this:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([ROUTES]),
    ProductModule
  ],
```

Yea, this should be a comment ... but there is no way I know of to format code in a comment.

If you have any code like this, that could be causing the problem.

Comment: It sounds more like he's using `RouterModule.forRoot` inside his feature modules.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Hence the reason I was hoping to see the imports statements they used ... not just the routes themselves.